# Play 2.x @ sign in route definitions

Tags: scala, playframework, routes

I'm learning the Play! framework (2.3.x). I am confused about the meaning of the '@' character in front of the controller in route definitions like this:

```
POST   /myresource/:id/custom   @controllers.MyResource.custom(id: Long)
```

As much as I can infer from the context I've seen this in, it probably has to do with the exact controller implementation (object vs class). Or am I completely wrong in this? I can't find anything in the docs and the code I've seen isn't exactly explanatory. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaRouting):

> Play supports generating two types of routers, one is a dependency
>   injected router, the other is a static router. The default is the
>   static router, but if you created a new Play application using the
>   Play seed Activator templates, your project will include the following
>   configuration in `build.sbt` telling it to use the injected router:
>
> ```
> routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
> ```
>
> The code samples in Play’s documentation assumes that you are using
>   the injected routes generator. If you are not using this, you can
>   trivially adapt the code samples for the static routes generator,
>   either by prefixing the controller invocation part of the route with
>   an `@` symbol, or by declaring each of your controllers as an `object`
>   rather than a `class`.

The equivalent in Java would be static vs non-static.

Comment: Ok that explains it I guess. The DI thing must be new to 2.4, the 2.3.x docs don't mention anything (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaRouting)

Comment: nop the DI thing is not new to 2.4, in 2.3- it would refer to controllers whose instances were obtained through Global.getControllerInstance see https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.0/JavaInjection and https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.0/ScalaDependencyInjection

Comment: @Jean thanks. Hadn't gone through DI documentation yet. A cross reference in the routing section would have saved me a lot of time and an unnecessary SO question :-)